# In-place progress output to the console: How to empty the current line

Tags: ruby, terminal

I have a Ruby script that outputs progress messages on the same line, using the carriage return character, like this:

```
print "\r#{file_name} processed."
```

As an example, the output changes from `'file001.html' processed.` to `'file002.html.' processed` and so on until the script completes.

I'd like to replace the last progress message with `Done.`, but I can't just write `print "\rDone."` because that piece of code outputs something like this:

```
Done.99.html processed.
```

I guess I have to empty the line after the last progress message and then print `Done.`. How do I do that?

Comment: Why don't you print "Done" with a lot of spaces after?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev because some terminals actually do line-wrapping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to send the sequence of bytes that corresponds to the terminfo
variable `clr_eol` (capability name `el`) after using `\r`. There are several
ways that you could get that.

Simplest, assume that there's a constant value. On the terminals I've checked
it is `\e[K`, but I've only checked a couple. On both of those the following
works:

```
clear = "\e[K"
print "foo 123"
print "\r#{clear}bar\n"
```

You could also get the value using:

```
clear = `tput el`
```

Or you could use the [terminfo gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-terminfo):

```
require 'terminfo'
clear = TermInfo.control_string 'el'
```

Comment: `clear = \`tput el\`` doesn't work where the `tput` command is not available (e.g. Windows).

Comment: Obviously it wouldn't. Not being able to completely rely on that being available is part of the reason I gave other alternatives.